# Eclipse error accessing CS41: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ide, eclipse

We have two different Orgs and nearly a dozen sandboxes on each.  Eclipse (Eclipse Standard/SDK,  Version: Kepler Service Release 2,  Build id: 20140224-0627) can successfully connect to every sandbox and production org, with the exception of the two sandboxes currently on CS41.  We get the following error:
**Unable to find valid certification path to requested target.**

Is anyone experiencing the same or do you have a suggestion?